# Are there any ways to naturally speed up my reaction speed without any drugs?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, neuroscience, cognitive-neuroscience, intelligence, reaction-time

I play a lot of video-games and did some research online and came to the conclussion that a certain set of things are linked to an above average reaction speed and an general improved cognitive function.

[Drinking coffee.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3942723/) I never drunk coffee but when I heard about it's benefits I started implementing it into my diet.

[Playing FPS or fast paced shooter games helps improve your overall reaction times?](https://www.polygon.com/2013/1/30/3932876/research-playing-first-person-shooters-improves-learning-abilities-cognitive-function)

[Watching 3D films](https://www.cinemablend.com/new/Science-Proves-Watching-3D-Movies-Can-Actually-Improve-Your-Brain-71579.html)

[Meditation](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S1053810010000681) I don't think I need to provide sources for that since everyone knows about it.

[Sleep](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3307962/) Self evident.

[Colder temperature improves mental performance in males but not in females, it's the opposite for women](https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2019/05/190522141829.htm)

And certain types of foods including those rich in antioxidants and omega-3 fatty acids.

Now many of those tips most people know about but are there any other secret ways that can get you to the next level that the average person doesn't know about?

Comment: There are other types of caffeine sources for you to try - especially green tea has a lot of additional benefits to improve overall physical condition :)